# How to reply comment using django and javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, csrf-token, django-mptt

Please, I need help with my code, I have been unable to figure out my mistake for two days. I have a comment system that work properly but I want user to be able to reply comments. My issue now is that the reply comment is not submitting as I keep having the error:

*This page isn’t working right now. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405*

Below is my view.py associated with it

```
class BlogDetailsView(DetailView):
    model = models.BlogPost
    template_name = 'home/blog_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_likes = get_object_or_404(models.BlogPost, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        post = self.get_object()
        context['comments'] = post.comments.filter(status=True)
        context['comment_form'] = NewCommentForm()
        total_likes = get_likes.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if get_likes.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context['total_likes'] = total_likes
        context['liked'] = liked
        return context

def add_comment(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(models.BlogPost, pk=pk)
    comments = post.comments.filter(status=True)
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment_form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            user_comment.post = post
            user_comment.save()
            return redirect('index:blog_details', pk=pk)
    else:
        comment_form = NewCommentForm()
    return redirect('index:blog_details', pk=pk)
```

Below is urls.py

```
app_name = 'index'

urlpatterns = [
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('images/favicon.ico'))),
    
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),

    path('blog/', BlogHomeView.as_view(), name="blog_list"),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailsView.as_view(), name='blog_details'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('blog/edit/<int:pk>', EditPostView.as_view(), name='edit_post' ),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/delete', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post' ),
    path('like/<int:pk>', views.LikeView, name='like_post'),
    
    path('job/', JobHomeView.as_view(), name="job_list"),
    path('job/<int:pk>/', JobDetailsView.as_view(), name='job_details'),

    
    path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),       
    path('category/<str:category_name>/', views.CategoryView, name='category_list'), 
    path('view_category/', views.ListCategory, name='view_category'), 

    path('<int:pk>/add_comment/', views.add_comment, name='add_comment')

]
```

The form.py code

```
class NewCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    parent = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Comment.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
         
        self.fields['parent'].required = False 
        self.fields['parent'].label = ''
        self.fields['parent'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'd-none'})

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('user', 'parent', 'content')

        widgets = {
            'user': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',  'value': '', 'id':'user_name', 'type':             'hidden'}),                                 
        }
```

And, the associate template code

```
 <!---View of comment for logged in user--> <br><br>
                    <div class="post-title">
                         {% with comments.count as total_comments %} 
                         <h2>
                             {{ total_comments }} Comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}                               
                         </h2>
                         <small>Discussion on: {{ object.title }}</small><hr>
                         {% endwith %} 
                     
                         {% load mptt_tags %} 
                         <div>
                             {% recursetree comments %} 
                             <small><b>{{ node.user }}</b> - {{ node.date }} ({{ node.date|naturaltime }})</small>
                             <div class="parent-comment" id="{{ node.id }}">{{ node.content|safe }}</div> 
                     
                             <hr>
                             <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="myFunction('{{ node.id }}')">Reply</button>
                             <div>
                                 {% if not node.is_leaf_node %} 
                                 <div class="children-comment">{{ children }}</div>  <hr>
                                 {% endif %}
                             </div>     
                     
                             {% endrecursetree %}
                         </div>
                     
                         <br><br>
                         <div>
                             <h2>Make a new comment</h2>
                             <form id="myForm" method="post" action="{% url 'index:add_comment' object.id %}"> 
                                 {% csrf_token %} 
                                 {{ form.media }}
                                 {{ comment_form.as_p }}                                                            
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add comment</button>
                             </form>
                         </div>
                     
                     
                         <script>
                             var user = "{{ user.id }}";
                             document.getElementById("user_name").value = user;
                     
                             function myFunction(id) {
                                 var existingForm = document.getElementById("newForm");
                                 if (existingForm) {
                                     existingForm.remove();
                                 }
                     
                                 var reply = document.getElementById(id);
                                 reply.insertAdjacentHTML(
                                     "afterend",
                                     ' <form id="newForm" method="POST" class="form-insert py-2">' +
                                         '<div><h2>Reply</h2></div>' +
                                         '<select name="parent" class="d-none" id="id_parent">' +
                                         '<option value="' +
                                         id +
                                         '" selected="' +
                                         id +
                                         '"></option>' +
                                         "</select>" +
                                         '<label for="id_content">Content:</label>' +
                                         '<textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" required id="id_content"></textarea>' +
                                         '{% csrf_token %}' +
                                         '<button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>' +
                                         "</form>"
                                 );
                             }
                     
                             $(document).ready(function() {
                                 $('#myForm').trigger('reset');
                             });
                         </script>  
                     
                         <style>
                             .parent-comment {
                                 border: 1px solid rgb(164, 172, 243);
                             }
                             .children-comment {
                                 margin-left: 5rem;
                                 border: 1px solid gray;
                             }
                         </style>
                     </div>
                     

                    <!---End of view of comment for logged in user
```

I have twerk the views, form, template and urls codes severally but the error persists. I checkedif the add_comment views allows the post method. I played around with the code that I lost my initial code but still have not figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your reply js code there is a problem - you don't have an action for the form

```
 <form id="newForm" method="POST" class="form-insert py-2">' +
```

should be somehting like

```
action_url = "{% url 'index:add_comment' object.id %}"
...
' <form id="newForm" method="POST" class="form-insert py-2" action="' +  action_url + '">'
```

Also your js form requires a user field which you are not currently supplying. Try adding:

```
 '<input type='hidden' name="user" value="{request.user.id}">'
```

somewhere in your form construction.

**OR**

Strictly speaking, if user is always going to be the request.user, you can remove it from your form definition

```
fields = ('parent', 'content')
```

and add it after validation in your view

```
        user_comment.post = post
        user_comment.user = request.user
        user_comment.save()
```

That way no one can edit the html before sending to impersonate another user.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some other changes that could help.

Comment: Thank you @SamSparx, you just saved my hassle. It works fine after deleting the user field from the form.py and adding it in the views.py. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Feel free to give it a tick if it was useful for you :-)